# Сортировка большого объема данных c++

Tags: c++, сортировка, qsort

Итак, нужно отсортировать csv файл, в нем 114318 записей, мне нужно было использовать быструю сортировку, я написал программу, но вот проблема, при сортировке более чем 2000 записей, вызывается ошибка

```
Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00D21F49 в proj.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack 
overflow (параметры: 0x00000001, 0x004A2FF8).
```

интернет говорит, что проблема в том, что происходит переполнение стека, я вынес все массивы в глобальную область, но это не помогло, скажите, как я могу отсортировать весь файл быстрой сортировкой? вот код:

```
int temperature(const Star* x)
{
    int psefdo_temperature= 0;
    if (x->spectral_type[0] == 'O')
        psefdo_temperature = 70;
    if (x->spectral_type[0] == 'B')
        psefdo_temperature = 60;
    if (x->spectral_type[0] == 'A')
        psefdo_temperature = 50;
    if (x->spectral_type[0] == 'F')
        psefdo_temperature = 40;
    if (x->spectral_type[0] == 'G')
        psefdo_temperature = 30;
    if (x->spectral_type[0] == 'K')
        psefdo_temperature = 20;
    if (x->spectral_type[0] == 'M')
        psefdo_temperature = 10;
    psefdo_temperature += -1 * (x->spectral_type[1] - '0');
    return psefdo_temperature;
}

void quicksort_temperature(Star array[], int lo, int hi)
{
    if (hi - lo > 1)
    {
        Star pivot = array[lo];
        int j = lo + 1;
        for (int i = lo + 1; i < hi; i++)
            if (temperature(&array[i]) <= temperature(&pivot))
            {
                Star temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
            j++;
        }
        quicksort_temperature(array, lo, j - 1);
        quicksort_temperature(array, j, hi);
    }
}


int main()
{
    Star* p = (Star*)malloc(120000 * sizeof(Star));
    int number_of_stars = 114318;
    FILE* f = fopen("1.csv", "r");
    char header[200];
    fscanf(f, "%s\n", header);
    for (int i = 1; i < number_of_stars; i++)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%ld,%s,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%s,%lf,%lf,%lf,%[^\n]\n",
        &p[i].hip, p[i].proper_name, &p[i].right_ascension, &p[i].declination,
        &p[i].magnitude, &p[i].absolute_magnitude, p[i].spectral_type, &p[i].x,
        &p[i].y, &p[i].z, p[i].constellation);
    }
    fclose(f);

    printf("sorting start");

    quicksort_temperature(p, 0, number_of_stars);

    char s[] = "sorted_by_temperature.txt";
    save_stars(s, p, number_of_stars);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Вот часть кода, где идет сортировка, в файле несколько полей, я сортирую по полю `spectral_type`, там лежат данные в формате `латинская заглавная буква, цифра`, примеры: `G1` `B0` `A3`, как заставить программу работать при `number_of_stars >2000`?

P.S. изменить алгоритм сортировки можно, только если он будет не медленнее данного

P.P.S объявление Star:

```
struct star
{
    long int hip;
    char proper_name[20];
    double right_ascension;
    double declination;
    double magnitude;
    double absolute_magnitude;
    char spectral_type[15];
    double x, y, z;
    char constellation[5];
};
typedef struct star Star;`
```

Comment: А почему нельзя воспользоваться готовой сортировкой? Почему необходимо писать свою? Скорее всего, у вас неудачные данные - и в результате вы получаете слишком глубокую рекурсию...

Comment: а как? я сортирую самописные структуры, и для каждого элемента мне еще и нужно считать численное значение температуры, я не знаю как сделать это стандартным qsort'ом

Comment: У вас С++, стандартный `sort`. Можно и `qsort`, просто несколько сложнее... Покажите объявление `Star` - как вам без него отвечать?...

Comment: я добавил объявление `star` в конец вопроса

Comment: Вы в чём работаете, в  VS? Как вариант попробуйте увеличить стек в VS это в свойствах проекта Linker/System/ Stack Reserve Size

Comment: Так все же как выглядит спектральный тип? Это всегда 2 символа? Тогда зачем вы выделяете 15? И я так и не пойму - у вас С++ или С? Если С++ - то к чему этот typedef?

Comment: можно перегрузить оператор сравнения и отправить в стандартный sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас C++, указанный в метках - то примерно так:

```
bool lessClass(const Star& a, const Star& b)
{
    const char * cls = "OBAFGKM";

    const char * ast = strchr(cls,a.spectral_type[0]);
    if (ast == 0) ast = cls + 7;

    const char * bst = strchr(cls,b.spectral_type[0]);
    if (bst == 0) bst = cls + 7;

    if (ast < bst) return true;
    if (ast > bst) return false;
    return a.spectral_type[1] < b.spectral_type[1];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Star* p = (Star*)malloc(120000 * sizeof(Star));
    int number_of_stars = 114318;

    ...

    sort(p,p+number_of_stars,lessClass);
}
```

Если С - то примерно так:

```
int compClass(const void * astar, const void * bstar)
{
    const char * cls = "OBAFGKM";

    const Star * a = (const Star *)astar;
    const Star * b = (const Star *)bstar;

    const char * ast = strchr(cls,a->spectral_type[0]);
    if (ast == 0) ast = cls + 7;

    const char * bst = strchr(cls,b->spectral_type[0]);
    if (bst == 0) bst = cls + 7;

    if (ast < bst) return -1;
    if (ast > bst) return 1;
    return a->spectral_type[1] - b->spectral_type[1];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Star* p = (Star*)malloc(120000 * sizeof(Star));
    int number_of_stars = 114318;

    //...

    qsort(p,number_of_stars,sizeof(Star),compClass);
}
```